# How to request a random select in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

any help would be appreciated in advantages.
My goal is to return a random select between to queries that both inserts data to my Bingo table. The value NOT chosen must be set to NULL .

```
insert into Bingo 
select @numrat , null,@gameid,GETDATE(), @magicColor, @ngjyraGogla1 

select @numrat ,(select top 1 nr from @allnr1 order by NEWID()),@gameid,GETDATE(), null, @ngjyraGogla1
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Why doesn't your code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
insert into Bingo ( . . . )  -- listing the columns is a best practice
    select @numrat , null, @gameid,GETDATE(), @magicColor, @ngjyraGogla1 
    union all
    select top (1) @numrat, nr, @gameid, GETDATE(), null, @ngjyraGogla1
    from @allnr1
    order by NEWID();
```